# FFmpeg - Rotating at angle

Tags: ffmpeg

I've been working through FFmpeg, but I have been unable to get a rotation to run from the examples they have on their site. I am trying to "wiggle" a video back and forth at a fixed point on the bottom - think a head moving left to right (and so on).

I am attempting to do this with the filter "rotate" (https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#rotate). Attempting to use their examples, I get an error.

This is what I have so far:

```
ffmpeg -i vid1.mp4 -i vid2.mov -loop 1 -i image.png -filter_complex "\
    [2:v]alphaextract, scale=240x160[mask];\
    [0:v] scale=240x160, rotate=A*sin(2*PI/T*t) [ascaled];\
    [ascaled][mask]alphamerge[masked];\
    [1:v]scale=480x360[background];\
    [background][masked]overlay=120:20"\
    -c:a copy 65B6354F61B4AF02_HD_sq.MOV
```

I am using "rotate" directly from an example in an attempt to get something to run at all.

The error I get back is:

```
[Parsed_rotate_3 @ 0x7ff4476045e0] [Eval @ 0x7fff5b3e3f00] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'T*t)'
[Parsed_rotate_3 @ 0x7ff4476045e0] Error occurred parsing angle expression 'A*sin(2*PI/T*t)'
[Parsed_rotate_3 @ 0x7ff4476045e0] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_rotate_3
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #1:0
```

If I remove 'A', 'T', 'sin', etc, rotate does actually work, but far from the desired behavior.

Am I missing something to expose those params?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the expression,

```
rotate=A*sin(2*PI/T*t)
```

`A` and `T` aren't literals. The user is meant to replace them with numerals, representing the amplitude in radians and period in seconds repsectively.

e.g.

```
rotate=2*sin(2*PI/3*t)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to the [transpose](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#transpose) filter, for example, Rotate 90 clockwise

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "transpose=1" output.mp4
```

For the transpose parameter you can pass:

```
0   90CounterCLockwise and Vertical Flip (default)
1   90Clockwise 
2   90CounterClockwise
3   90Clockwise and Vertical Flip
```

Comment: I'm not really going for a full flip in a direction. I'm trying to do some left to right to left (etc) movement, pivoting on an angle.